# Slow transfer over wget and curl on RPi4

Tags: ethernet, pi-4

I have issue with curl and wget transfer speed on my new Raspberry Pi 4 1GB.
Pi is sonnected to the router by ethernet cable. When I try to download for example a large test file or something from github transfer speed is around 30-40KB/s. It does not matter if the output is a file on sd card or /dev/null. When I run speedtest it shows 500Mbps and that is what my ISP offers.

When I try run the same curl/wget commands on my other RPi2b speed is maxed out for its 100Mbps ethernet.

Comment: Ah, Rpi4B 1GB download 30-40kB/s is ridiculously slow. I have a Rpi4B 1GB/2GB to test right now. Can you give me the exact wget command for a very large file "wget http: ..." and any check speed commands your are using for me to test for you to compare?

Comment: I am using this site for a mentioned large files https://www.thinkbroadband.com/download and speedtest is this one https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli

Comment: Many thanks. I hope to try it in 60 minutes, and let you know the results.  Cheers.

Comment: I first tried using my Win10 to download 1GB from thinkBoardBand and 2.5GB rpi full image from Rpi download site. The 1GB predicted 45 minutes, and 2.5GB predicted 3 hours. This is strange, it usually should take much less than that. I have not tried Rpi4B yet, but I don't  expect any good news. Is it because the brexit reason?

Comment: Anyway, I am now downloading using Rpi4B the same 1GB file, the estimated time varies from some 5min to 13min left. Ned to wait. Will report progress later.

Comment: By the way, your speed test site says it is only for debain, it is OK for raspbian or Win10? The Rpi4B is still downloading. I need to use my stop watch to see time elapsed :). Perhaps I should try the small files 5MB/10MB.

Comment: And Win10 download the thinkboardband's 100MB takes 1min 23 sec. Is this rough results good enough for you to verify something?

Comment: And my Win10 speed test says 920~930 Mbps. Is it useful for you?

Comment: Now the Rpi4B 2GB downloading thinkboardband 1GB results: started 18:34, finished 18:45. so it is about 9 minutes.

Comment: BIG apologies. The results earlier was Rpi4B WiFi 2.4G.  Now I tried downloaded the thinkboardband 1GB file and it took only TWO MINUTES.I have not tried the speed test, because the test asks for postal code which I have not.  I guess they only test UK sites.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is. I will try to reinstall raspbian today and hope this will help.

Comment: Yes, sometimes the OS gets corrupted for unknown reasons. So reflashing the SD card is often a good trick. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: What is the speedtest and from what site do you download?

Comment: I just found out that reason for this is my router. There are a few similar topics where people describe the same issue. There are a 3 solutions that I can think of: new router, use wifi not ethernet limit or limit eth0 to 100mbit via `ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full`. For now my choice is wifi.